# Reducing cell size of DEM for processing reasons?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, resolution, solar-radiation

I need to calculate the solar radiation for a region of interest, and I am using the 'solar radiation' tool implemented in ArcGIS (10.1) and a DEM with cell size 1x1. It is 3 days now that ArcGIS is processing the DEM, and it is at 31%. 
I was wondering if it is a sound approach to convert (how?) the DEM at a coarser resolution (say, 10x10). Furthermore, since my aim was to use the obtained raster as an Independent Variable in a Logistic Regression model, and since the other rasters I will use are at cell size 1x1, I am wondering if there is anything methodologically wrong in introducing disparities in the raster used as far as cell size is concerned?

Comment: If you have several cores on your computer you should split your raster in parts. Take the amount of cores minus one or two (check in Task Manager --> Performance how many you have). Then you can run those parts in separate processes. From what I understand ArcMap can only use one core for each process, and this method will let you use more of available resources without (significantly) slowing down your computer. I guess available RAM also matters, though.

Comment: thank you. Yes, unfortunately I was thinking of slipping the DEM in chunks, say 6. But this will prove a pain since, besides global radiation, I am interested in the changes of received radiation across 1 year. This implies that I will end up with 12x6 rasters, and I will be forced to combine them month by month.

Comment: While that does sound tideous, you then have to evaluate which will take most time from you versus how fast you need the results. Possibly you can automate the process of merging rasters as well.

Comment: This is a follow up question. As a result of what I described earlier, after two weeks of calculation, I got 12x6x4 rasters representing the Solar Radiation per month in a study area (i.e.: 12: months, 6: the chunks of the study area; 4: the types of raster obtained, namely diffuse radiation, direct radiation, duration, etc). Now, I have to merge them: this is proving to be very time-consuming. @Martin was referring to the possibility to automate the process. I am wondering how?